# Google Drive API: Force login popup to login again or to logon as another user

Tags: javascript, authentication, popup, google-drive-api

Logon works fine but after the famous 3600 seconds it will expire. Have read some information about it that you can request a new token. Okay, but this is not the topic of today in this question.

After the session has expired or I want to change to another user account, I cannot figure out how to popup the login window or to force to popup the login window.

In the API-example they use the `immediate` property, when set this to false the window will pupop but.... only a flash second! It popups and disappear. This never happen when the user has never login before or when you remove all cookies from the browser.

I was thinking to destroy all cookies but are on another domain so I can not invalidate these to force the popup of the login window. Have tried a couple of things, to recreate objects, invalidate the token etc, it never wants to popup again even when the session is expired.

What can I do about this?
Here is some of the code I have made (NOTE: oauth2 and all necessary things are already loaded)

```
o.cdGoogleAutorize = function( fCallback, bPopUp, bForce )
{
  var w = window,
      fc = (typeof fCallback == 'function')?fCallback:function(){},
      bp = (typeof bPopUp == 'boolean')?bPopUp:false,
      clid = w.GAPI_CLIENT_ID+'.apps.googleusercontent.com';

  try 
  {
   if( !w.gapi || !w.gapi.auth || !w.gapi.auth.authorize )
    { return false; }
  } catch(e) { return false; }

  var aScope = w.GAPI_AUTH_SCOPES.split(','),
      i = aScope.length;    

  while( i-- )
   { aScope[i]='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/'+aScope[i]; }

  aScope.push('openid');

  if( bForce )
  { gapi.auth.setToken('');
    $d('force'); gapi = o.newInstance( gapi ); 
  } // invalidate object/token etc //gapi.auth.setToken(token)

  // authorize
  gapi.auth.authorize({
    client_id:clid
    ,scope:aScope 
    //user_id: uUserId,
    ,immediate: bp?false:true
  }, 
  function(op)
  {
   if( typeof op == 'object' && op != null && op.client_id == clid )
   {
    // $d( op.scope );
    // gapi.client.load('oauth2', 'v2', function() 
    //{
     gapi.client.oauth2.userinfo.get().execute(function(resp) 
     {
       //$d( resp );
       if( !resp.code && resp.id ) 
       { fc( resp.id ); }
       else {
              //if( !bPopUp )
               { fc(false); }
            }
     });
    //});
   }
   else fc(false);
  }); 


   };
.........
.........
.........
```

To clearify some things:

- $d() is shortcut to a debug window
- o. is the encapsulated object and
  a shortcut to 'this'

Some code onclick (jquery) for the login button:

```
 $j('#login_button').bind('click', function()
 {
   o.cdGoogleAutorize( function()
   {
     // do something 
   }, true, true );
 });
```

Any ideas how to force the login popup window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

But if there are any other ideas please let me know. I realize that using this solution logout ALL drive connections for apps and other google services. Better use a warning dialog between this action.

I have use the code of the logout button of my account and use this in an iframe. After loading this I request again to login. I add the following code to the top of the body of the function:

```
  if( bForce )
  { 
    var $oFrame = $('<iframe class="hidden" src="https://www.google.com/accounts/Logout?service=wise&amp;continue='+
                      'https://drive.google.com/?authuser%3D0"></iframe>');
    $oFrame.bind('load', function()
    {
      // Give it a sec
          setTimeout( function() 
      { o.cdGoogleAutorize( fCallback, true ); 
        $oFrame.remove();
      }, 1000 );
    }).appendTo('body');
    return true;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, you need to [request offline access](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#offline) which will give you a refresh token. You can use the refresh token to request a new access token after the first 3600 seconds expire, no need to bug the user to login again.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the answer. read that page already. As I explained before, no matter what it was impossible to popup the login window to logon as another user. With the code I post yet, this is possible, just a few min after you.

Comment: Jay Lee < Do you know how to find out a session is expired?

Comment: gapi.auth.getToken() is always an empty object?

Comment: to determine if a access token has expired, mark when it was received and see if it's been 3600 seconds (actually, you should use the expires_in attribute value but that's always 3600). In reality, it's probably worth refreshing a minute or two before the token expires to make sure you don't run into any time sync issues.

Comment: Jay Lee < Ah, thanks, I will figure it out. But what happen when the user refresh the page? Does this also automatic refresh? Very important to know when using a timer